# how to remove a item from list in Windows Phone 8 App C#

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

When the user taps on the particular item in the list new page opens and there he can see full details of the particular item. He can delete particular item if he thinks he don't want that. My problem is the file was not deleting from the list.

```
public partial class DetailsPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    SavedData prkdata = new SavedData();
    SavedDataList parkinglistobj = new SavedDataList();
    IsolatedStorageFile Settings = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
    int index;

    public DetailsPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();        
        //this.Loaded += MainPage_Loaded;
    }        

    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {              
         string selectedIndex = "";

        if (NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("selectedItem", out selectedIndex))
         {
             index = int.Parse(selectedIndex);
             try
             {
                 parkinglistobj.Clear();

                 if (Settings.FileExists("CardItemList"))
                 {
                     using (IsolatedStorageFileStream fileStream = Settings.OpenFile("CardItemList", FileMode.Open))
                     {
                         DataContractSerializer serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(SavedDataList));
                         parkinglistobj = (SavedDataList)serializer.ReadObject(fileStream);
                     }
                 }

                 ParkListBox.ItemsSource = parkinglistobj.Where(i => i.ID == index).ToList();

                 //String itemselected = parkinglistobj.Where(i => i.ID == index).Select(i.CardName).ToString();
                 //MessageBox.Show(itemselected);
             }
             catch
             {
                 //
             }
         }
    }

    private void DeleteFile(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //ParkListBox.SelectedItem = parkinglistobj.Select(i => i.ID == index);
        //SavedData item = ParkListBox.DataContext as SavedData;
        SavedData item = parkinglistobj.Select(i => i.ID == index) as SavedData;
        //SavedData item = ParkListBox.SelectedItem as SavedData;
        parkinglistobj.Remove(item);
        MessageBox.Show("Deleted Successfully");
    }
}
```

Comment: Start with removing the empty `catch` block - it's swallowing any exception that occurs, so you have no ides if there is an error or not.

Comment: Also, the meat of your `DeleteFile` method is commented out, so it's not surprising that it doesn't do anything.

Comment: Actually I tried normally. But while posting in this blog I commented it... to show all in how many ways I tried it and Try method is in other function which tries to display content. Content was displaying but it was not deleting. @DStanley

Answer (score 0):

In the DeleteFile event handler you should remove the item and then re-serialise it back to the CardItemList file

Comment: I am new developer @Chairag Shah can you say me clearly how to reserialise back if ?

Answer (score 0):

You to need to communicate back to your View (which is your `ListBox`) that something has changed so it needs to update/redraw its Content.

Unforunately, a generic `List<T>` will not automatically do this for you.  What you need is to use an `ObservableCollection<T>` instead.

[MSDN: ObservableCollection Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), pay attention to this part of the  description:

> Represents a dynamic data collection that provides notifications when items get added, removed, or when the whole list is refreshed.

If you used it correctly any addition and deletion to the collection will result in the `ListBox` redrawing itself.